# Should you coat exposed roofing nails with neoprene washers

Tags: roof, waterproofing

Was on my roof cleaning pine needles and noticed that my roof had a number of exposed nails that have neoprene washers near flashing and on the last ridge shingle on each peak.

Should I seal over these with roofing tar or will the washer be sufficient protection? There is no signs of leaking from inside the attic and the roof is ~ 5 years old

Comment: ...it's usually EDPM, not Neoprene. Tar would be likely to damage it, if anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of the neoprene is to make the seal. No additional sealant is typically required.

See also: Millions of ribbed steel roofing screws with rubber washers under their heads.

[image]